# ultra small float values on stm32f4

Tags: floating-point, stm32

Here is simple code for stm32f4

```
void main(void)
{
    float sum = 1.0;
    uint32_t cnt = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        for( cnt = 0; cnt < 1000; cnt++ )
            sum += 2.0e-08;

        printfUsart("%f\r\n", 
                            sum
                            );
    }
}
```

There is no changes of variable `sum` value.
If i summarize in loop this value: `sum += 2.0e-07;` it increase. 
I use "gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2014q4" compiler with this compile and linker flags:

```
PROCESSOR = -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

So, how work with ultra small float values? I need it to implement Matlab generated code in stm32f4 firmware to realize some filtering functions.

Comment: it's [`int main(void)`, not `void main()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: I think void main() is okay, because we have an embedded micro-controller. There is no need of returning a value, because main has no calling thread or OS.

Comment: With floats, definitely use Kahan sum, but also consider multiplying everything by 10^6 or 10^8 during (and before) the loop as well...and then dividing afterwards. That's typically how similar issues are resolved in fixed point.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 *binary32* floating-point format has 24 bits of precision, which amounts to approximately 7 decimal digits (the correspondance is not exact because binary is not decimal).

This is not enough to distinguish 1 and 1.00000002. The binary32 value immediately above 1.0f is [exactly](http://ideone.com/b7lcLg) 1.00000011920928955078125.

Your available options are

1. to use the type `double` for the variable `sum`, assuming that `double` is mapped to IEEE 754 *binary64* with its 53 bits of precision, or
2. to improve accuracy by using a better summation algorithm. The most famous is [Kahan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm):

   ```
   void main(void)
   {
     float sum = 1.0;
     uint32_t cnt = 0;
     float c = 0;

     while(1)
     {
       for( cnt = 0; cnt < 1000; cnt++ )
       {
           float y = 2.0e-08f - c;
           float t = sum + y;
           c = (t - sum) - y;
           sum = t;
       }

       printfUsart("%f\r\n", sum);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility is to optimize your filtering functions regarding to the used coefficients.

Here is the solution for manually optimization of your example:

```
void main(void)
{
    float sum = 1.0;
    uint32_t cnt = 0, temp = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        for( cnt = 0; cnt < 1000; cnt++ )
            temp += 2;
        sum = sum + temp*e-08;

        printfUsart("%f\r\n", 
                            sum
                            );
    }
}
```

An disadvantage is, that you have to do this optimization manually and that it is not generic, but it can save a lot of computing time because there are less floatingpoint-operations.